# What happens when you yield a activerecord object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Can someone help me understand the below code.

```
def self.with_optimistic_lock(attrs)
  begin
    payment = where(attrs).first_or_create
    yield(payment)
    payment.save!
  rescue ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError, ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid, ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
    retry
  end
end
```

Where `attrs` is hash of parameters. `Post` is class inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base`.

This is code snippet from https://github.com/fantgeass/rails-test-tasks/blob/master/app/models/payment.rb

Comment: Nothing unusual happens. Same as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It yields just like any other block would, making the yielded object available to the block:

```
Post.with_optimistic_lock(:name => "Foo") do |post|
  # The 'post' variable contains the ActiveRecord object yielded from the method

  # Once this block ends, the method will resume at the `payment.save!` line
end
```

Comment: Can you explain how will it resume back to payment.save!?

Comment: The `yield` call inside `with_optimistic_lock` blocks until the calling block is complete, then once the block is executed, the `with_optimistic_lock` method continues. You might read http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_blocks.htm for an overview on how blocking/yielding works.